# What does "it fell to the Boor" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Ran into this:

> He came to a desk. On it lay a metal paper knife with an ornate handle. Would it be sharp enough? He reached for it and knocked over a small brass jar. Stamps spilled out of it and **it fell to the Boor with a clatter**. "Hey," Mrs. Barrows yelled from the kitchen, "are you tearing up the pea patch?" Mr. Martin gave a strange laugh. Picking up the knife, he tried its point against his left wrist. It was blunt. It wouldn't do. [Source](http://jameshilston.com/pages/reading/catbird_seat.htm)

It is obvious the man has knocked over the jar so made it fall off the desk, the stamps spilled out and the contact between the metal jar and the floor made a clatter, noise. However, What does **it fell to the Boor with a clatter** mean exactly? I checked the meaning of Boor but apparently here it has another sense other than [the normal ones](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/boor?showCookiePolicy=true). Is it an idiom or something?

Comment: Is there ANY way that it's a typo of "floor"?

Comment: Other than that, I'm struggling. The fact that it's capitalised is indicative of a product name, or similar. At first, I thought it referred back to Mr. Martin himself, but the capitalisation didn't ring true for that explanation.

Comment: @JMB A pal just made the puzzle. It is originally the floor and happened due to an optical character recognition (OCR) error.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that's an optical character recognition (OCR)  error.

The intended word is "floor" which would look very much like "Boor" on a blurry scan, or if the original text used a [ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature#Stylistic_ligatures) between the "f" and "l".

In this case, it is saying that when the object fell to the ground (floor), there was a noise (clatter).

Comment: +1 Certainly correct. Google Books returns 8 hits on "fell to the Boor", every one of which is an OCR error.

Comment: Wow! you are quite right. I checked it in my printed version of the story. Now should I delete this question? And would you kindly say what **it wouldn't do** at the end mean? Does it refer to the sharpness of the knife alone?

Comment: It refers to the sharpness of the knife, but it's "do" meaning "suffice". The knife was not good enough/wouldn't suffice for the job at hand.

Comment: "It wouldn't do" implies that the knife needs to be sharp to accomplish whatever Mr. Martin requires it for. We can leave it up to the mods on deletion - it might be helpful to someone else as it sounds like this is a common OCR error.

Comment: I wouldn't delete the question. These OCR errors [pop up every now and again](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47413), and it's good for people to be made aware of them. No need to feel bad about it. As the OCR scanner says: _Sh! It happens..._